# Index an array of arrays with an array of indexes in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of arrays [of arrays ...] such as:

```
array[a][b][c][d][e]
```

And an array of indexes:

```
indexes = [ a, b, c, d, e ];
```

Is there an elegant way to index the array of arrays using the array of indexes?

The brute force method I am using is:

```
element = array[indexes[0]][indexes[1]][indexes[2]][indexes[3]][indexes[4]]
```

**EDIT**

To be clear, I would to be able to use an arbitrary array of indexes from 1 to n elements, where n is the depth of array nesting.

So given the above example of five-level nested array of arrays, and given an index array of:

```
indexes2 = [ a, b, c ];
```

I would expect to retrieve:

```
array[a][b][c]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to go through the `indexes` and get the element you want.

```
// array[a][b][c][d][e]
var indexes = [ a, b, c, d, e ];

var element = indexes.reduce(function(prev, curr){
    return prev[curr];
}, array);
```

Comment: That appears to do the job exactly, and is not likely a solution I would have stumbled onto on my own. Thank you.