# Finding an item in an array of arrays via an array of indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an arbitrarily deep nested array of objects, simplified here as:

```js
interface IComponent {
  title: string;
  components?: IComponent[];
}

const data: IComponent[] = [
  {
    title: 'First Component',
    components: [
      {
        title: 'Nested Component 1',
        components: [
          {
            title: 'Child 1 of: Nested Component 1'
          },
          {
            title: 'Child 2 of: Nested Component 1'
          },
          {
            title: 'Child 3 of: Nested Component 1'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: 'Nested Component 2',
        components: [
          {
            title: 'Child of: Nested Component 2'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I have an array of the indexes in this nested array that point to one object to return:

```js
const indexMap: number[] = [0, 0, 2];
```

Currently, I'm cheating by creating a string to eval as such:

```js
let evalString = 'data';

indexMap.forEach((index: number, iterator: number) => {
  if (iterator === 0) {
    evalString += `[${ index }]`;
  }
  else {
    evalString += `.components[${ index }]`;
  }
});
```

Resulting in a string such as: `data[0].components[0].components[2]`

Which works, but I'd like to avoid using eval. I've tried a few variations using `.reduce()` but I seem to be stumbling over first getting `data[index]` and then accessing the `components` value.

Is there a better/simpler/safer way of getting to `data[0].components[0].components[2]` given this data structure?

This question: [Index an array of arrays with an array of indexes in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265081/index-an-array-of-arrays-with-an-array-of-indexes-in-javascript) is similar, but with a different data structure.

This question is also similar: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path) but my root object has a slightly different data structure.

Comment: `indexMap.slice(1).reduce(({ components }, index) => components[index], data[indexMap[0]])`? Or you could simplify the start with `indexMap.reduce(({ components }, index) => components[index], { components: data })`. This isn't really a [tag:typescript] question, this is just [tag:javascript].

Comment: Wow @jonrsharpe - that's incredibly helpful, and now so obvious when I see it. Please add answer with your comment code and I'll gladly accept it. Thank you so much. I sincerely appreciate the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Comment: @HereticMonkey that example is accessing properties of an object via string syntax. In my case, I have an array of objects and an array of indexes.

Comment: "Resulting in a string such as: data[0].components[0].components[2]

Which works, but I'd like to avoid using eval."

Comment: Right, running `eval()` using that string is accessing the items by index, not dot-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the process by *starting* with an object where your `data` array is the `components` prop, then it's just a single `.reduce` over the `indexMap`:

```js
indexMap.reduce(({ components }, index) => components[index], { components: data })
```