# Add entry to array of objects using array of indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, eval

I have the following scenario: I have an array of objects (TreeItems) which could contain nested arrays. And I have another Array with indexes. Now I would like to change the TreeItems array using the indexes array to access a specific tree item and depending on if there is a nested array called "items" I would like to either append the existing one or add a new one. And mostly important, I would like to get rid of the evil eval.

So in my example I try to add a new entry at TreeItems[4][0][0] but the indexes in the brackets should be added dynamically from the indexes array but I'm not quite shure how to do this.

I have searched of course and [found this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265081/index-an-array-of-arrays-with-an-array-of-indexes-in-javascript), but it doesn't quite work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const TreeItems = [
  { text: "Lvl 0", items: [{ text: "Lvl 0-0" }, { text: "Lvl 0-1" }] },
  { text: "Lvl 1" },
  { text: "Lvl 2", items: [{ text: "Lvl 2-0" }, { text: "Lvl 2-1" }] },
  { text: "Lvl 3" },
  {
    text: "Lvl 4",
    items: [
      {
        text: "Lvl 4-0",
        items: [
          {
            text: "Lvl 4-0-0",
            items: [{ text: "Lvl 4-0-0-0" }, { text: "Lvl 4-0-0-1" }, { text: "Lvl 4-0-0-2" }],
          },
          { text: "Lvl 4-0-1" },
          { text: "Lvl 4-0-2" },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const indexes = [4,0,0];
let comString = '';
for(let i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
  if(i === 0) {
    comString = "TreeItems[" + indexes[i] + "]";
  } else {
    comString += ".items[" + indexes[i] + "]";
  }
}

if(eval(comString).items !== undefined) {
  eval(comString).items.push({"text": "Test-item-appended"});
} else {
  eval(comString).items = [{"text": "Test-items-added"}]
}
console.log(comString);
console.log(eval(comString).items);
console.log(TreeItems);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `eval` or any kind of dynamic code generation to do this. As a matter of fact, there are no programming problems that would warrant the use of `eval` unless you're explicitly looking to execute a block of foreign JavaScript code.

If you want to access the nested children of `TreeItems` using an array of indices as the path, you can create a variable for storing the child at depth `n`, starting from 0, and then repeatedly overwrite it with the child at depth `n + 1`, until you have accounted for all the indices in the path:

```js
function getTreeItem(path) {
    // get first child, whose index is at path[0]
    let currentChild = TreeItems[path[0]];
    
    // for indices at path[1] and further, overwrite currentChild with the next child
    for (let i = 1; i < path.length; i++)
        currentChild = currentChild.items[path[i]];
    
    return currentChild;
}
```

Note that using for loops and let statements is a bit verbose and goes against the coding style for modern JavaScript. The proper way to do this is by using Array.prototype.reduce, as suggested in the answer you found. The original question was about arrays of arrays, whereas in this case you're accessing an array of objects with a property named `items`, and your function must account for that.

The following code is functionally equivalent to the above code:

```js
function getTreeItem(path) {
    return path.reduce(
        (currentChild, currentPathIndex, depth) => {
            // if currentPathIndex is path[0], set currentChild to the currentPathIndex-th child of TreeItems
            if (depth == 0)
                return TreeItems[currentPathIndex];
        
            // otherwise, set currentChild to the currentPathIndex-th child of currentChild.items
            return currentChild.items[currentPathIndex];
        },
        // let the initial currentChild be null and the initial depth be 0
        null
    );
}
```

[Read more about Array.prototype.reduce at MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Once you have obtained a reference to the parent node, you may add items to it in exactly the same manner as proposed in your question:

```js
function addTreeItem(parentPath, text) {
    const parent = getTreeItem(parentPath);
    
    if (parent.items)
        parent.items.push({text})
    else
        parent.items = [{text}];
}

addTreeItem([4, 0, 0, 0], "added item");
addTreeItem([4, 0, 0, 0], "appended item");
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and yes, this is great for reading the branch at that path. My issue is now how I would use this information to add something to the TreeItems array at that path, depending on if the items array at that path exists or not. Meaning what I did just above the console.logs at the bottom of my code in that last if statement but without the eval's.

Comment: @bbasmer I updated my answer. The `getTreeItem` function lets you add items in exactly the same manner as you did in your question.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a million! I learned something usefull here again. :-)

Comment: @PeterSeliger That is actually true, thanks for pointing that out but in the context of my application I can always be sure that the array of indexes always contains existing data because it gets generated from an existing tree. In a different scenario though you are definately right. Nevertheless I'll try to put up your solution below and give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @bbasmer ... The above implementation of `getTreeItem` does already fail at accessing something non existing but very simple  like ... `getTreeItem([3, 0])`. Invoking the function like that does raise/throw a `TypeError`. Of cause one can not invoke ... `addTreeItem([3, 0], "added item");` either, due to the former error. But one could have expected the creation of a new `items`-array including a new item for the 4th item of the OP's `TreeItems` structure because it already does exist as `{ text: "Lvl 3" }`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible implementation was a function which utilizes a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach.

Such a function does either access an `items`-item through the additionally provided array of sub-`items` indices, or it does create such an item at the targeted tree-depth by also creating any not yet existing tree-structure; hence the example's function name ... `createAndOrGetItem`.

The [reducer (callback) function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#syntax) would iterate the array of indices, where with each iteration step the function's return value either is the to be processed next-level `items`-array or, as for the final iteration, the targeted item itself.

Depending on whether an item does exist or whether an existing item does feature an `items`-array one just does access these references or one does create and refer to them. For one of such tasks the provided example code uses the [*nullish coalescing assignment operator / `??=`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment).

```js
function createAndOrGetItem(items, itemIndices) {
  return itemIndices
    .reduce((itemsArray, itemsIndex, idx) => {

      const isLastItemIndex = (idx >= itemIndices.length - 1);
      const item =
        itemsArray[itemsIndex] ??= { text: 'A new item has been inserted.' };

      if (
        !isLastItemIndex && (
          !item.hasOwnProperty('items') || !Array.isArray(item.items)
        )
      ) {
        item.items = [];
        item.text = 'The items array has been created.';
      }

      // - the final return value has to be the item itself
      //   ... otherwise proceed with reducing the items array.
      return isLastItemIndex && item || item.items;

    }, items);
}

console.log(
  'createAndOrGetItem(TreeItems, [4, 0, 0]) ...',
  createAndOrGetItem(TreeItems, [4, 0, 0])
);
console.log(
  'createAndOrGetItem(TreeItems, [3, 0, 0]) ...',
  createAndOrGetItem(TreeItems, [3, 0, 0])
);
console.log(
  'createAndOrGetItem(TreeItems, [4, 0, 2, 4]) ...',
  createAndOrGetItem(TreeItems, [4, 0, 2, 4])
);

console.log({ TreeItems });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  const TreeItems = [
    { text: "Lvl 0", items: [{ text: "Lvl 0-0" }, { text: "Lvl 0-1" }] },
    { text: "Lvl 1" },
    { text: "Lvl 2", items: [{ text: "Lvl 2-0" }, { text: "Lvl 2-1" }] },
    { text: "Lvl 3" },
    {
      text: "Lvl 4",
      items: [
        {
          text: "Lvl 4-0",
          items: [
            {
              text: "Lvl 4-0-0",
              items: [{ text: "Lvl 4-0-0-0" }, { text: "Lvl 4-0-0-1" }, { text: "Lvl 4-0-0-2" }],
            },
            { text: "Lvl 4-0-1" },
            { text: "Lvl 4-0-2" },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
</script>
```